# How to clone LVM thin provisioning volume?

Tags: lvm, thin-provisioning

I googled many times but couldn't find an answer. What I want is cloning an LVM thin provisioning volume to another thin volume.

For now I know `dd` can clone a thin volume as following:

`dd if=/dev/mapper/vg_thin01 of=/dev/mapper/vg_thin02 bs=1M`

But the new cloned volume will be full size! How can I make it to sparse/thin volume?

(Actually the thin volume will be used for DomU storage in Xen or KVM )

Comment: The thin provisioning is a bit on the bleeding edge side of things.  There may simply be no tools yet to accomplish this.

Comment: Yes.. Actuall I saw very little messages about this topic on internet.

Answer (score 3):

Cloning a thin volume is as simple as taking a snapshot of the to-be-cloned volume. When using thin volumes, snapshot and new volumes really are the same thing, with different default flags.

From the [kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/thin-provisioning.txt):

> Once created, the user doesn't have to worry about any connection
>     between the origin and the snapshot.  **Indeed the snapshot is no
>     different from any other thinly-provisioned device** and can be
>     snapshotted itself via the same method.  It's perfectly legal to
>     have only one of them active, and there's no ordering requirement on
>     activating or removing them both.  (This differs from conventional
>     device-mapper snapshots.)

So it is perfectly legal to snapshot a thinly-provisioned volume to create a CoW clone. From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/lvmthin.7.html):

```
Example
       Create first snapshot of an existing ThinLV:
       # lvcreate -n thin1s1 -s vg/thin1
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this hasn't been correctly answered (yet) because the OP appears to be indicating two different volume groups, a source and a destination. So I'll try to answer it.

Note: This response assumes that a reference like `/dev/mapper/vg_thin02` indicates a *volume group* in accordance with the usual Linux convention, and that any pool or thin volume in that group would be followed by a dash like so: `/dev/mapper/vg_thin02-volA`.

When cloning between two volume groups (or two thin pools) on the same machine, for each source volume do:

```
fstrim /mnt/volA
umount /mnt/volA
lvcreate -kn -ay -V sizeofvolA -T vg_thin02/poolname -n volA
dd if=/dev/mapper/vg_thin01-volA of=/dev/mapper/vg_thin02-volA conv=sparse
```

Continue with "volB", "volC", etc. as necessary. The `conv=sparse` argument stores the new copy in a sparse, thin-provisioned way.

The `fstrim` and `umount` lines show that some form of trim/discard is necessary on the source volume before it is taken offline and duplicated. If the volume is normally mounted with the `discard` option this may not be necessary.

For cloning between two different machines, you can use `ssh` on the source machine in conjunction with `dd` on the destination:

```
gzip -2 </dev/mapper/vg_thin01-volA | ssh user@address "zcat | sudo dd of=/dev/mapper/vg_thin02-volA conv=sparse"
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you need is a cloning utility that recognises filesystems. Preferably unmounted ones as cloning a running FS is a recipe for a disaster.

[partclone](http://partclone.org/) is one such utility. My ubuntu 16.10 and OpenSUSE Leap:42 have it in their package manager repositories. Fedora 25 OTOH doesn't.

You can use [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) as well which is a live CD backup / recovery tool supporting LVM2 as well.

I have found several more on [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/disk_cloning).

Answer (score 0):

I understand that further to @shodanshok reply you can then activate that snapshot for normal use as per the man documentation:

```
6. activate SnapLV
       Thin snapshots are created with the persistent "activation skip"
       flag, indicated by the "k" attribute.  Use -K with lvchange or
       vgchange to activate thin snapshots with the "k" attribute.
```